# Read Codeigniter external folder from Laravel app

Tags: laravel, codeigniter

I've an old customer project in Codeigniter which is pretty huge and I need to migrate it to Laravel without writing it all over.

I cannot write it all from scratch (even if I'd really love to) due to the fact is very big and still in use, so my solution is to create an Auth "bridge" from Codeigniter to Laravel.

Basically I need to keep the Codeigniter app running and all old stuff will be read from there, while all new logics will be implemented inside Laravel.

My idea is to have Codeigniter app inside a `ci` folder inside my root folder project:

```php
laravelnewsite/ci
```

The only thing I would like to do is skip Laravel routing only in the `ci` folder.

Currently if I just navigate to `laravelnewsite.test/ci` does not work and returns a Laravel-404 error, even if I move it to `public/` or to `storage/app/public/ci` (with a symlink) I still cannot read it.

I think is a matter of making an exception for the `ci` folder but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

first, you should use only one of them.
even if you manage to send the request to `code igniter`, then you will have to send it back to `laravel` after the "Auth bridge" ? how will laravel recognize the auth?

anyway, back to your question. One `PHP` solution would be to include the `index.php` file of code igniter in the `index.php` file of laravel and exit after that. (The structure of the request might not be the correct one for CI, check the .htaccess)

`public/index.php`

```
<?php

if ({condition}) {
    require_once({{codeigniter.index.php}});
    die();
}

/**
 * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
 *
 * @package  Laravel
 * @author   Taylor Otwell <taylor@laravel.com>
 */

define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));
```

other solutions would require a well crafted `.htaccess` or `nginx/apache config file` to redirect the request to the right php file.